# How to check whether the folder is created, and if not, create it?

Tags: files-and-directories

Consider a .nb file. How to check whether the folder is present in notebook directory, and if not, create it?

Comment: Check with `FileExistsQ` and create with `CreateDirectory`: If[! FileExistsQ[file], CreateDirectory[file]].

Comment: Just use `CreateDirectory`. If directory already exists you'll get `CreateDirectory::filex` message. If non-directory file exists, with given name, you'll get `CreateDirectory::dirf` message. You can use `Quiet` and/or `Check` to ignore/react to those situations.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
With[{dirname = FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "mydir"}]},
 Switch[FileType[dirname],
  None, CreateDirectory[dirname] (* create dir *),
  Directory, Null (* do nothing *),
  File, Print["File with same name already exists!!"] (* error! *)
 ]
]
```

Ref: [`FileType`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FileType.html), [`CreateDirectory`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CreateDirectory.html)

Ideally, also check if `CreateDirectory` succeeded.

Comment: I forgot about `FileType`, it is a nice alternative to `FileExistQ[""]` issue.

Answer (score 5):

As noted by [jkuczm](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/14303/jkuczm) in a [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/179434/how-to-check-whether-the-folder-is-created-and-if-not-create-it#comment469190_179434),  we can attempt to create the directory unconditionally but tolerate the case that the directory already exists:

```
Quiet[
  CreateDirectory[{FileNameJoin[NotebookDirectory[], "mydir"}]]
, CreateDirectory::filex
]
```

This approach differs from the test-then-create approach in that it precludes the possibility of another process sneaking a file operation between the testing and creation.  Of course, this possibility is not relevant for typical single-user operation.

If rather than leaving the directory empty we wish to immediately create a contained file, we can create both the directory (as needed) and the file in a single step:

```
CreateFile[
  FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "mydir", "myfile"}]
, CreateIntermediateDirectories -> True
]
```